# mt19937 and defaulted constructor cause class initialisation to be wrong?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, stl, visual-studio-2015

I encountered an odd problem that only showed itself in Release mode but not in Debug mode (working with VS2015 RC). The second class member of `Aggregate` gets initialised with the same values as the first one, even though it should be default-initialised.

Even more strange, once I change `Base() = default;` to `Base() {};`, the odd behaviour is gone. But they should be equivalent, shouldn't they? Did I find a VS bug?

I was able to boil it down to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    Base() = default; // elicits the odd behaviour on VS Release mode
    //Base() {}; // works
    Base(std::vector<int> m) : m(m) {};
    size_t get_m() const { return m.size(); };
private:
    std::vector<int> m;
    std::mt19937 engine;
};

class Aggregate {
public:
    Aggregate() = default;
    Aggregate(Base one, Base two) : one(one), two(two) {};
    Base get_one() const { return one; };
    Base get_two() const { return two; };
private:
    Base one;
    Base two;
};

Aggregate make_aggregate() {
    Base b1(std::vector<int> { 1, 2 });
    Base b2(std::vector<int> { 3, 4, 5});
    return Aggregate(b1, b2);
};

int main() {
    Aggregate a1 = make_aggregate();
    Base base = Base();
    Aggregate a2(a1.get_one(), base); // a2.two.m should be empty and it is
    Aggregate a3(a1.get_one(), Base()); // a2.two.m should be empty but it's set to a2.one.m

    // should print '2, 0', and it does:
    cout << a2.get_one().get_m() << ", " << a2.get_two().get_m() << endl;
    // prints '2, 2' on VS in Release mode! (and '2, 0' in Debug mode, and on clang):
    cout << a3.get_one().get_m() << ", " << a3.get_two().get_m() << endl;
}
```

Am I in the land of undefined behaviour here (e.g. does the `mt19937` **have to be** static?) or is my code fine? Is it a VS bug? `clang-3.5` was fine with the code both with and without `-g`.

Comment: Does the bug disappear if you remove unused `std::mt19937` or if you return get_one/two by reference ?

Comment: Yes, the bug disappears if I remove the `mt19937` (or if I make it `static`), hence the title. And no, returning a `&` or `const&` doesn't make it disappear.

Comment: It works fine with `/O2` on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/. Maybe you should try to replicate as many of the settings you're using in Release mode there and see if the problem appears. If it doesn't, I'd say it looks like a compiler bug that was fixed since RC.

Comment: Yea, I just tried that too actually. I'll just wait for the RTM and try again there, I think it's being released in 6 days or so.